# Unable to use Http put method to send data to an URL

Tags: java

I unable to use put method to send data to particular link.. Please find below the code.Let me know if i have to make any change

```
public class test {
    private static String url = "http://semldvw0728.google.net/.svc/web/testrequests/";
    private static String urlconnection;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    StringBuffer xmlString = new StringBuffer();

    xmlString.append("<TestRequest>");
    xmlString.append("<DateRequested>2011-12-20</DateRequested>");
    xmlString.append("<DemCapID>893467</DemCapID>");
    xmlString.append("<DemCapVersion>1</DemCapVersion>");
    xmlString.append("<IBIS_ID>13530</IBIS_ID>");
    xmlString.append("<ProjectName>LTS</ProjectName>");
    xmlString.append("<RequestedBy>ktmq331</RequestedBy>");
    xmlString.append("<SampleNumber>SN1033645061</SampleNumber>");
    xmlString.append("<Status>Sample Ordered</Status>");
    xmlString.append("</TestRequest>");

    System.out.println("xmlString :" + xmlString.toString());
    url = url + 893467;
    System.out.println("URL : " + url);

    try {
        System.out.println("URL : " + url);
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        PutMethod putMethod = new PutMethod(url);
        client.setConnectionTimeout(8000);
        putMethod.setRequestBody(xmlString.toString());
        System.out.println("statusLine>>>" + putMethod.getStatusLine());
        System.out.println("statusLine>>>"+           putMethod.getResponseBodyAsString());
        putMethod.releaseConnection();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Be more specific. Add more information. What is the problem? Is there an error? etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to make a call to [execute](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/HttpMethodBase.html#execute%28org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpState,%20org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection%29), or you could use the HttpClient object you've created to [call this](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/HttpClient.html#executeMethod%28org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethod%29).

So maybe add this line after you're setting the request body for your putMethod...

```
client.executMethod(putMethod);
```

Comment: Could you please explain me how to create HttpClient

Comment: I added how you would call given the code you've provided and linked you to the docs.  That should be sufficient.

Comment: @user1042983: `HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();`

Comment: I've just updated to point out you should put the line after you set your request body; not after setting the timeout on the client as I originally said.